# Adding XML sub elements to an ArrayList with DOM4J

Tags: java, xml, xml-parsing, dom4j

here's a sample of my XML file:

```
<agregator1 id="CSP">
    <id>int</id>
    <type>string</type>
</agregator1>
<agregator1 id="Microgrid">     
    <id>int</id>
    <type>string</type>
</agregator1>
```

I've never worked with `DOM4J` and I've read the documentation but I can't seem to get the sub-elements into `ArrayList`'s, I'm trying to do the following:

```
arrayList1: id, type
arrayList2: int, string
```

here's my code:

```
for ( Iterator i = root.elementIterator(); i.hasNext(); ) {
    Element foo = (Element) i.next();
    if(foo.attributeValue("id").toString().equals("CSP"))
    {
      //what am I missing here?
    }
}
```

I've searched a lot, and I can't find any solution since I can't do `foo.getChildNodes()`.

Any sugestions?

EDIT: I need to get the node names without using `elementText(String)` (or anything like this) because I need my code to work even if the XML file is changed, without editing my code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem. Thanks to all who tryed to help.
To all the people who are searching for a similar solution, here's my code:

This is the above method, completed:

```
public static ArrayList<Element> readSubElements()
   {
       ArrayList<Element> subElements = new ArrayList<>();

        Element root = configs.XMLreaderDOM4J.getDoc().getRootElement();
        for (Iterator it = root.elementIterator(); it.hasNext();){
            Element foo = (Element) it.next();
            if(foo.attributeValue("id").equals("VPP"))
            {
               for (Iterator it2 = foo.elementIterator(); it2.hasNext(); )
               {
                  Element temp = (Element) it2.next();
                   subElements.add(temp);
                   System.out.println(""+temp);
               }
            }
        }

       return subElements;        
   }
```

And a new method I've created:

```
public static void getTagNames() {

   ArrayList<Element> elements = readSubElements();
   ArrayList<String> list1 = new ArrayList<>();
   ArrayList<String> list2 = new ArrayList<>();
   setSize(elements.size());

   for (Iterator it = elements.iterator(); it.hasNext();) {
      Element entry = (Element) it.next();
      list1.add(entry.getQualifiedName());
      list2.add(entry.getText());
   }

   setTagNamesAL(list1);
   setTagContentAL(list2);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I can help you with this 2 solutions:

**Methode 1**: *select all element agregator1 after that verify only* attributeValue if equal a CSP.

```
Element root = document.getRootElement();
List<Element> listElement = root.selectNodes("./agregator1");
if (listElement != null) {
    for (int j = 0; j < listElement.size(); j++) {
        Element el = listElement.get(j);
        String attrValue = el.attributeValue("id", "");
        if (attrValue.length() > 0 && attrValue.equals("CSP")) {
            // do your code
        }
    }
}
else {
    // element not found
}
```

**Methode 2**: *do this in just 1 line, use xpath*

```
Element rootElement = doc.getRootElement();
List<Element> elementNeeded = rootElement.selectNodes("./agregator1[@id='CSP']");
if (elementNeeded != null && elementNeeded.size() > 0) {
    // element found do your code
}
else {
    // element not found
}
```

Comment: Can you do that? List doesn't take parameters

Comment: Isn't that the exact same thing I've done? I need a way to get the agregator1 child nodes...

Comment: for the first methode:
the element "el" (Element el = listElement.get(j);) has all child nodes for get one just do this:
el.selectnodes("./[NameOfElementYouLike]") ==> your get list for all element with name = [NameOfElementYouLike].
2- for the second methode you current element is "elementNeeded": this element has all childs nodes